# Query to select field only if two values and count is satisfied

Tags: sql-server, query

I have a table with 4 Columns:

ID, Context (smallint), StartedAt (datetime), FinishedAt(datetime)

The Context field can be 1-5

I need to select the last date of "FinishedAt" field, **but only if Context have exactly 2 rows with value 1 AND 2**.

How to achieve this?

In the resultset below, I wanna to return only rows 2 and 3, because row 1 only have 1 occurrence of Context "1", and rows 4-5 are outdated:

| ID | Context | StartedAt | FinishedAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-03-14 03:50 | 2023-03-14 04:04 |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-03-13 03:50 | 2023-03-13 04:18 |
| 3 | 1 | 2023-03-13 03:50 | 2023-03-13 04:02 |
| 4 | 2 | 2023-03-12 04:20 | 2023-03-12 04:40 |
| 5 | 1 | 2023-03-12 04:00 | 2023-03-12 04:30 |

Comment: Hi and welcome to dba.se! How does one distinguish between sets of fields that have contexts 1 & 2?

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/32281)

Comment: @Vérace the table only accepts 5 records per day, 1 record of each "Context" type. I updated the post for better understanding.

Comment: Sample data as *text* not images would help. What happens if the date fields cross a day boundary? What happens if there are more than two rows per day?

Comment: @Charlieface sorry, image replaced. The date field don't cross a day boundary because is a background service which processes a file in about 15 minutes. If the result comes back with more than 2 lines, the application triggers a notification event to be handled (it's an exception scenario)

Comment: Why are rows 4 & 5 "outdated"?

Comment: @Vérace because there are newer records in the table and what matters is the last in this context is the most recent record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a windowed count to check for at least two rows per set. Then use `TOP 1 WITH TIES` to get the first set.

```sql
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
  ID,
  Context,
  StartedAt,
  FinishedAt
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      date = CAST(FinishedAt AS date),
      count = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(FinishedAt AS date))
    FROM YourTable t
) t
WHERE count > 1
ORDER BY
  date DESC;
```

You can alternatively use `DENSE_RANK` to get the first set instead of `TOP 1`

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just another question: Doesn't this subquery tend to slow down as the table grows?

Comment: Yes it can do, but so does the self-join solution. In certain situations an indexed aggregate view can work well with a self-join. Note also that the `CAST` means it can't use indexes anyway unless you use a computed column